# Comment dire "I'm renewing my closet"?

Tags: traduction

So far my questions have all been about clothing, ahah... So, how do I say "I'm renewing my closet"? Here "closet" is referring to clothes and not the space where you keep them.

Merci d'avance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Je suis en train de refaire ma garde-robe.

Comment: *Je **renouvelle** ma garde-robe* is even closer.

Comment: Merci à vous deux !

Comment: Je vous en prie.